# Multiple Match Multiple return excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that looks like:

[image: DATA SET]

I have two input blocks:

Employee:

Week:

I want the formula to be able to return the tasks if both the name and week match. Even if the task is assigned to multiple people.

I have tried:

```
=INDEX(Task,SMALL(IFERROR(IF(MATCH("Name",Employee,0)=MATCH("Week",Week,0),ROW(Task),"NONE"),""),ROWS(A1:A1)))
```

Comment: How does one know which tasks are associated with each person?

Comment: They are in a row. But the same task can be associated to multiple people.

Comment: use pivot table, put Week, Employee and Task as rows (hopefully in tabular format) and filter the week and name of your concern.

Comment: @SJR apologies I have edited the post for clarity

Comment: Thanks Oliver, the end result is to get employees to track their hours per task, so it will be updated weekly on individual workbooks. Pivot tables would, from my knowledge, require more manual labour

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("name",B1))`
to see if the name is in the cell.

For more information you can look at
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/contains-specific-text.html

Answer (score 1):

If one person can be assigned several tasks in one week, you can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2,$B$2:$B$7))*($G$2=$C$2:$C$7)))*ROW($A$2:$A$7),COLUMN(A1)))
```

Copy it right as needed. If you want to hide errors, use `IFERROR (..., "")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your current formula can be adapted to: **CTRL + SHIFT +ENTER**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Task,SMALL(IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Name",Employee)))*("Week"=Week),ROW(Task)),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

it is untested though. You have to be careful with `INDEX`- and `ROW`-ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (MATRIX) solution. For CONCAT() you need OFFICE 365.
It works also if there are more rows where week and name matches.

```
=TRIM(CONCAT(IF((C2:C8=G2)*(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(F2,B2:B8)))),A2:A8 & " ","")))
```

[image]